# What do "embedded mode" and "single server mode" in graph databases mean?

Tags: graph, neo4j, graph-databases, blazegraph

Many books and articles on graph databases talk about "embedded mode" and "single server mode".

For example, the [Wikipedia article on graph databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database) mentions the following:

> Blazegraph supports high availability (HA) mode, embedded mode, single server mode.

What do "embedded mode" and "single server mode" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Embedded mode, Neo4J can be invoked or run in another application which is not standalone Neo4J. For instance, if you have a Python / Django app, you can 'embed' Neo4J but calling for Neo4J libraries.

In the Single server mode, the Neo4J and its applications works alone, for instance, like a recommender system or outlier detection. In this case, Neo4J may not have any dependence on other applications.